# Javascriptvariable in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, loops, session

i got a question.
I have this for-loop in Javascript and in PHP some Sessionvariables which are declared like:
PHP:

```
$Vorname = $_POST['Vorname'];
$_SESSION['anzahl'.$Vorname] = $_POST['anzahl'];
```

There are more than one Sessionvariable, its like `SESSION['anzahl'.'div0']`, `SESSION['anzahl'.'div1']`, `SESSION['anzahl'.'div2']` etc.

In Javascript i want to get the value from the different `Sessionvariables` with a loop.

How to get the "i" from the JS-for-loop into the PHP echo?
Or is there an better way to do this?
JS:

```
for(var i =0;i<Bestellungen;i++){
     Sessionanzahl.push("<?php echo $_SESSION['anzahl'."div".i]?>");
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the whole php array to a javascript variable as json and merge into your other array

```
var phpArray = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['anzahl']) ?>;

Sessionanzahl = Sessionanzahl.concat(phpArray);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
The problem is that $_SESSION['anzahl'] isnt a array.